# Vectorize MATLAB if loop

Tags: matlab, loops, vectorization

There are plenty of related questions to this, but I couldn't find one exactly related. I need to do some computations if an `if` condition is satisfied. 
Here is the code without vectorizing:

```
if check(w,t)~=1
 do all this
end
```

There is a loop over `w` and `t` outside this `if`, and I need to vectorize the `w`. So, I want something like

```
if check(:,t)~=1
do all this (only for those w for which the condition was satisfied)
end
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The best answer to your question highly depends on what do you want to do when the conditions `check(w,t)~=1` or `if check(:,t)~=1` are satisfied.

Nevertheless, you can use the function `find` to find the indices of the elements on the matrix `check` that, in your case, are `~= 1`:

```
[r_no_1,c_no_1]=find(ckeck ~= 1)
```

If you need to work by column, you can use `find` this way:

```
for col=1:size(ckeck,2)
   ck_no_1=find(ckeck(:,col) ~= 1)
   m=ckeck(ck_no_1,col)*100
end
```

now, at each iteration, `ch_no_1` contains the row indices (of the col-th column) whose element are different from 1.

Hope this helps,

Qapla'

Comment: There is no need to use `find` in the example you have given.  Removing the `find(` and the trailing `)` will give the same result more efficiently.

Comment: @PhilGoddard thank you for the suggestion, you're right; nevertheless, since in the question is not specified what to do when the condition is verified, having directly the indeces might be more of help than having an array of logical.

Comment: Well, thanks for your answer but I know I can find indices of elements which have the check to be 1, 0. But how do I proceed after finding those, in a vectorized way? Also, your question of what happens when conditions are satisfied- many computations, loops, function calls.

Comment: The answer I've posted contains an example (even if very simple) on how to use the indices: it multiplies by `100` the values in the `check` matrix that are different from `1`. If you need more complex examples you have to post the code you are working on in order to allow understanding what type of _omputations, loops, function calls_ you are dealing with.